# Error when running multiple instances with protractor and cucumber

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I'am a user of cucumber and protractor with automation test, I have a problem with configuration multicapabilities.

When I have a `count` greater than 10 I am seeing the below error but only on Linux environments. I can set count > 10 of windows without issue.

**config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
const Reporter = require("../support/reporter_login2/reporter");

exports.config = {
    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
    seleniumAddress: ,
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    maxSessions: 60,
    allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
    multiCapabilities: [{
        // 5 chrome sessions will start, each running 1 spec file at a time, until all 10 finish
        browserName: 'chrome',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 20,
        count: 15,
        client_key: "api_key",
        client_secret: "api_secret"
    }],

    /*capabilities: {
      browserName: process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || "chrome",
      'chromeOptions': {
       //'args': ['--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile'],
        'args': ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile']
      }
    },*/
    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
    specs: ["../features/login2/*.feature"],
    // resultJsonOutputFile: "./reports/json/protractor_report.json",
    onPrepare: function () {
        var chai = require('chai');
        chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
        chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
        chai.should();
        global.expect = chai.expect;
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        require('babel-register');
        Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
    },
    cucumberOpts: {
        //strict: true,
        format: 'json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json',
        require: ["../stepDefinitions/login2/*.js"],
        tags: "(@login2_1Step1)"
        //@manualTask1Step1 or @manualTask1Step2 or 
    },
    onComplete: function () {
        Reporter.createHTMLReport();
    }
};
```

**Error**

```
✖ And I want to click the Create Button # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:183
[chrome #21]        StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
[chrome #21]          (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.119)
[chrome #21]          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
[chrome #21]            at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
[chrome #21]            at parseHttpResponse (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
[chrome #21]            at doSend.then.response (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
[chrome #21]            at <anonymous>
[chrome #21]            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
[chrome #21]        From: Task: WebElement.getText()
[chrome #21]            at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
[chrome #21]            at WebElement.schedule_ (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2010:25)
[chrome #21]            at WebElement.getText (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2277:17)
[chrome #21]            at actionFn (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:89:44)
[chrome #21]            at Array.map (native)
[chrome #21]            at actionResults.getWebElements.then (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:461:65)
[chrome #21]            at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
[chrome #21]            at TaskQueue.execute_ (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
[chrome #21]            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
[chrome #21]            at asyncRun (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
[chrome #21]            at /opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
[chrome #21]            at <anonymous>
[chrome #21]            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)Error
[chrome #21]            at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:459:27)
[chrome #21]            at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:91:29)
[chrome #21]            at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (/opt/perform/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:831:22)
[chrome #21]            at World.<anonymous> (/opt/perform/Desktop/AutomatedTests_/stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:187:18)
[chrome #21]    - And I want to tsleep 4 seconds # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:198
[chrome #21]    - And I want to insert name # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:212
[chrome #21]    - And I want to tsleep 3 seconds # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:230
[chrome #21]    - And I want to select the desidere date # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:245
[chrome #21]    - And I want tosleep 3 seconds # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:290
[chrome #21]    - And I select the desidere date # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:275
[chrome #21]    - And I want tosleep 3 seconds # ../stepDefinitions/login2/feat1_stepUno.js:290
```

Help me guys thanks!!

Comment: Which number is greater than 10?

Comment: Hi @DublinDev, 15, but with windows there isn't this problem.

Comment: Haha no sorry, I meant what is the significance of the number 10, are you setting  maxInstances? maxSessions? or where are you setting this number?

Comment: ahah sorry, I setting 10 in count, but maxInstances is 20 and maxSessions is 60.

Comment: What does `count` refer to? Where is `count` used? How are you changing this the value of count?

Comment: sorry, 15 in count. @DublinDev

Comment: The count is the number of browsers that are opened. This variabile is setting in config file. @DublinDev

Comment: Could you maybe add to this question the capabilities section of you config and the command you use to start the Protractor execution?

Comment: @DublinDev ok ok!

Comment: @DublinDev 
Sorry but I could not insert the configuration file

Comment: The config file is there, no worries! I'm not hugely familiar with Cucumber or Linux so not sure how much additional help I can give right now. I may have a look again when I have some additional free time.

Comment: thanks!! @DublinDev

Comment: You can probably remove most of the above comments as they no longer contribute useful information to the question. That said, how the the resources of your windows and linux machines compare? You could potentially be pushing your linux machine too hard

Comment: @DublinDev ok ok thanks!!

Comment: In the config.js is possibile to insert a timer for the opening of the browsers?
For example, start 5 sessions now and another 5 sessions after 5 seconds.